# Visual Studio 2017 Pro - creating a Xamarian Form from template doesn't generate files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a Xamarian Form template from inside of visual studio all that's created in the root folder.  I'm lost has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what fixed it for me.

Windows: Windows 10
VS: 2017 PRO

Okay, so run VS as admin, and then install platforms via SDK package manager. And then create your template.

Apparently the problem is two fold, one the project templates cant get created without platforms and 2, you have to run as admin to install the platforms